# Display firebase child objects in listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. I'm trying to query the firebase database and display all the child objects of the results in a ListView. I've no errors but nothing is being displayed. It doesn't crash but it doesn't do anything either. Please help me out.

The contents of my database:
[image: Contents of my database]

Here's my code for data retrieval:

```
 imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                key = search.getText().toString().trim();
                Firebase newRef = new Firebase("https://stockmanager-142503.firebaseio.com/Items");
                Query query = newRef.orderByChild("Idno").equalTo(key);
                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        Map<String,Item> td = (HashMap<String,Item>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                        List<Item> valuesToMatch = new ArrayList<Item>(td.values());
                        myAdapter myadapter=new myAdapter(getActivity(),valuesToMatch);
                        mlistView.setAdapter(myadapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setMessage(firebaseError.getMessage())
                                .setTitle("Error!")
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();


                    }
                });
```

Here's my adapter class:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Item> items;
    private Context mContext;


    public myAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> items) {
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        Item item=items.get(i);
        if (view == null) {
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rowitem, viewGroup, false);
        } else {
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)view;
        }
        TextView text1=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        TextView text3=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        TextView text4=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
        TextView text5=(TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text5);
        text1.setText(item.getIdno());
        text2.setText(item.getName());
        text3.setText(item.getBrand());
        text4.setText(item.getCost());
        text5.setText(item.getDate());


        return null;

    }
}
```

Here is the item class:

```
public class Item {
    private String Type;
    private String Name;
    private String Brand;
    private String Cost;
    private String Date;
    private String Store;
    private String Idno;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getIdno() {
        return Idno;
    }


    public String getCost() {
        return Cost;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return Brand;
    }




    public String getStore() {
        return Store;
    }



    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in `onChildAdded` and see if it gets triggered?

Comment: Yup.The method is not being triggered. What to do?

Comment: I'd check whether `onCancelled()` is triggered, which I think it may be. Also: you're using the Firebase 2.x SDK. While this *may* work, I'd recommend using the newer 3.x SDK that is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/).

Comment: It's not triggered either.

Comment: What is the value of key right before you add the childEventListener and are you sure that value is actually in your database?

Comment: Next step is to eliminate the edit box. So what happens when you use `Query query = newRef.orderByChild("Idno").equalTo("dwcr56191RMA");`? Note that I'm essentially trying to show how you can zoom in on the actual problem. This is the only way you're efficiently going to be able to debug this, because StackOverflow is a really inefficient way to troubleshoot code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That link doesn't work

Comment: @AndréKool I checked that. The value is in the databse

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Another thing to note is that your Adapter will never display any items, even if you do fix your Query issue.  You are returning `0` or `null` from every method, which will tell the list there is nothing to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Apparently, the query returned a list of objects and hence I replaced the Hashmap with a for loop to getchildren and add them to a List. But my listview simply wouldn't display the retreived data. Finally, I used the firebase UI List Adpater given below and that fixed it. Thanks everyone!

```
  imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View view) {
                                          key = scanContent;
                                          Query q = dbRef.orderByChild("idno").equalTo(key);
                                          FirebaseListAdapter<Item> adapter =new FirebaseListAdapter<Item>(getActivity(),Item.class,R.layout.rowitem,q) {
                                              @Override
                                              protected void populateView(View v, Item item, int position) {
                                                  TextView text1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                                                  TextView text2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                                                  TextView text3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                                                  TextView text4=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                                                  TextView text5=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text5);
                                                  text1.setText(item.getIdno());
                                                  text2.setText(item.getName());
                                                  text3.setText(item.getBrand());
                                                  text4.setText(item.getCost());
                                                  text5.setText(item.getDate());
                                                  solditem=item;
                                              }
                                          };
                                          sell.setText("Add this result to Sold Items List?");
                                      sList.setAdapter(adapter);
                                      }
                                  });
```